# How to create a circular UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am having issue creating a circular `UIImageView`. If I were to manually set the `corderRadius` to a value, eg. 50, it will have rounded corner. But when I try to set it as half of the frame's height or width (`frame.width / 2` or `frame.height / 2`), it doesn't work. Somehow, the frame is `(0, 0, 0, 0)` when I try to print it.

And here is my code,

```
import UIKit

class TestIconController : UIViewController {

let icon: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.width / 2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadLogo()
}

func loadLogo() {
    view.addSubview(icon)

    // Constraints
    icon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    icon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
  }

}
```

Comment: That's because you are not setting a rect (frame) to `imageView`.

Comment: Add to @ElTomato comment .. Use `Lazy var` in these type of situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override this function.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        icon.layer.cornerRadius = icon.bounds.size.width / 2
        icon.clipsToBounds = true
        icon.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

Comment: It worked ! Why is it icon.bounds instead of frame ?

Comment: You can also use a frame instead of bounds.

Comment: I see. I have actually tried doing this but somehow it did not work for my actual project. Might need to check through it again. Anyway thank you!                      PS: I think because I was using viewWillLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 1):

You may also make a base class for it for batter handling; Like

```
class UICirlceImageView : UIImageView {
    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews();

        let layer:CALayer = self.layer;
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2.0;
        layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

then, do it like this

```
//let icon: UICirlceImageView = { // You may initialize like this as well
let icon: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UICirlceImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    //imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // Don't know if it is needed
    return imageView
}()
```

Note: The answer given by Rushabh is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this extensions

```
extension UIImageView {

    func setRounded() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

In your case you can inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews** call

```
icon.setRounded()
```